# SQL Server datatype to hold numers with more then 39 digits

Tags: sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

I am looking for the best SQL Server datatype to hold identity numbers with more then 40 digits. 
The `NUMERIC` datatype limited to 39.

Comment: That is not used for calculations, right? Use a string

Comment: Just remember, if you sort by your "string identity" value, that it will use alphanumerical sorting so you cannot rely on identity as a sort key. So you might also use two columns to represent the numbers instead of one if you need the numerical values to be more than just identity.

Comment: The question is: why do you need this? If you do a trillion (= 10e12) inserts per second for a trillion years, you'll still have headroom in 10e39. Are you averaging a trillion operations per second? Do you think your system will be around for a trillion years? If you answered "yes" to both then you need this. If the answer to either one is "no", then you don't.